# How can I install Bootstrap Studio?

Tags: software-installation

How can I install Bootstrap Studio on my Ubuntu system.

I can't find any tutorial.

Comment: Bootstrap Studio for Linux can be downloaded here https://bootstrapstudio.io/

Comment: I doownlode it usig github, than how can I install it on my ubuntu Os

Answer (score 1):

On the [github](https://github.com/bootstrapstudio/bstudio) page of Bootstrap Studio, they have clearly given the steps to install it

> ## Installation
>
> The script is available on `npm`. To install it:
>
> `npm install -g bstudio`
>
> This will create a global `bstudio` command which you can call from the
> terminal.

Comment: This is an interface for Bootstrap Studio, not the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you purchase the Bootstrap Studio from the Bootstrap Studio's [official site](https://bootstrapstudio.io/) they will offer the `.Appimage` version for Linux.
Unlike `.deb` packages `.Appimage` does not require installation.

All you have to do just Right-click on the Application -> Properties -> Under the Permissions tab check Allow executing file as program

[image]

p.s.

In case you don't see the download link from the homepase, here it is
https://bootstrapstudio.io/download